# Apple late early 2009 MacBook Pro does not wake (easily) from sleep

Tags: macos, hardware-failure, sleep, macbook-pro

My MacBook Pro does not wake up from sleep.  Someone told me (because she also had a problem with the same symptoms as mine) there is a sensor at the hinge at the bottom of the display that tells the laptop to sleep or to wake up when the screen is open or closed. It was suggested that a problem with this sensor could be causing my problem.

Does anyone know how to fix the sensor?

Thanks in advance!

It's most likely a hardware problem. However I'm not sure because this problem was happening earlier, but when I installed OS X Yosemite on it yesterday it may have made the problem *worse*. In fact this morning it wouldn't wake up so I had to restart it. I never had to do that before.

Comment: Fix a hardware problem via command, yep, that's how we do it here.

Comment: I wasn't sure if it was a hardware problem. For all I know it could be a software problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a PRAM reset

> - Shut down your Mac.
> - Turn on your Mac.
> - Immediately press and hold the Option-Command-P-R keys. You must    press this key combination before the gray screen appears.
> - Continue holding the keys down until your Mac restarts, and you hear    the startup sound for the second time.
> - Release the keys.

I've seen this fix all sorts of funky hardware related problems

Comment: My mom has os x yosemite and the start up works slightly differently, but I'll try what you suggested. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I did as you said and the whole system seems to run a lot faster. I think ram usage is lower and cpu usage is lower as well. I still have to do some testing to see if it resolved the problem with waking up from sleep. Thank you seems to have helped already!

Answer (score 0):

Can you see the sensor/switch?  If so, while the laptop is open, try activating it to fool the laptop into thinking you've closed the cover and observe whether the machine goes to sleep.  If you're confident you've properly engaged the switch, then you know it's defective and it needs to be replaced.

Failing this, check any relevant settings to ensure the laptop isn't configured to stay awake despite the lid being closed.  If you confirm the settings are set such that it *should* go to sleep when the lid is closed, but it refuses to do so, you have a bad switch and the laptop will require repair.

Comment: The question is about waking up tho, not sleeping.

Comment: If the switch is defective as the OP is wondering, testing its function by attempting to put the laptop to sleep will effectively confirm the defect.  If the laptop goes to sleep when the switch is activated, then one can safely conclude *a defective switch isn't the reason the laptop won't wake up*.

Comment: it really depends, and I disagree.  The switch may close fine, but be sticky and not open correctly.  If it were me, I would definitely use your test to see what I learned from it, but you can't eliminate "defective switch" (or hinge issue) based on the fact that the system goes to sleep correctly when the switch is manually prodded. I have a sticky reed switch in a piece of equipment, all I have to do is thump it to get the switch to reopen.

Comment: I see your point. Obviously we're getting into the minutia of troubleshooting a switch that could be only partially defective.  Hopefully my answer will give the OP a method for testing the switch that, while perhaps not able to identify *all* possible failure states, will be useful for the majority of possible cases.

Comment: I did the test that the answer above suggested and I think if may have fixed the problem more testing and time needed before I know for sure. It made the whole system run faster for sure. The cpu and ram levels now look excellent! I will try what you suggested if the test above doesn't end up fixing the problem.